# How do I select a specifc node using System.Xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document:

```
<Item>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Title>Title1</Title>
   <Rank>1</Rank>
</Item>
<Item>
   <ID>2</ID>
    <Title>Title2</Title>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
</Item>
```

This document has ten items it, the problem I am having is that I will select the Title2 ID 2 and Rank 1.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      XmlNode titleNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Title", NAMESPACE).Item(i);
      XmlNode asinNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ID", NAMESPACE).Item(i);
      XmlNode SalesNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SalesRank", NAMESPACE).Item(i);
 }
```

This is how I load the document.

```
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: I wish people would start using `System.Xml.Linq`. Every time I see people struggling with the horrible `System.Xml` API I shed a single tear. Also I don't see any XPATH being used here.

Comment: What exactly is the loop supposed to achieve? This is not the best way to iterate over a set of XML nodes.

Comment: @Oded I have ten items I want to update in my database, other than writing the code ten times what would be the way to get ten items?

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Item[ID='"+i.ToString()+"']");
XmlNode titleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Title");
XmlNode asinNode = node.SelectSingleNode("ID");
XmlNode rankNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Rank");
```

Comment: If you want something a bit more performant, switch your XmlDocument for an XPathDocument and navigate that instead.  Much quicker, but it's read only.

Comment: Node is null trying to select it this way.

Comment: That would be the case if your XML has another level above what's shown (presumably you have a root element around the two item elements). Either change the above to include a / and then whatever that container element is called to the start of that first SelectSingleNode xpath or change the first / to // to choose the items regardless of their depth (slower and prone to issues if Item can contain other Item elements).

Answer (score 0):

You could use XML (de-)serialization: Just create a quick class for Item. full sample in [XmlSerializer.Deserialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) docs.

Of course, this is just one among many techniques to parse XML (XPath, Linq to XML,...). Make your pick.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example using XPath which I believe is what you really need.

```
let doc = XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml ("<As><A><B>1</B></A><A><B>2</B></A></As>")
let n = doc.SelectSingleNode("As/A[B/text() = '1']")
```

Comment: I have added how I actually load the document

Comment: The loading process isn't relevant. The XML can be loaded in any way; it's the node selection method that's at play here.